# Multiple Host Effect on SEO?

Tags: seo, web-hosting

I am running the primary portion of my website on Google App Engine and using that to generate about 30% of the actual pages on the website and then I am using WordPress to run the Updates section which is around 70% of the pages from the site.  Is there any effect on SEO or how the website shows up in Google searches?

I would imagine that there is no effect but I wanted to see if there is anything that I can do to make sure it is that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines don't care about the technology of a webpage. As long as you're following good SEO practices, your content loads fast, etc, as Matt Cutts says: *you're in pretty good shape* :)